# Enable remote JMX monitoring for Spark running on DataStax Enterprise

Tags: apache-spark, jmx, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

What steps are required to perform on an standard AMI DSE installation on AWS EC2 to enable remote JMX monitoring?

I did following steps but I am not able to connect using VisualVM:

1. Create /etc/dse/spark/conf/metrics.properties
2. Copy&paste contents of https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.4/conf/metrics.properties.template
3. Uncommented these lines:

   - org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink
   - *.sink.jmx.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink
   - master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
   - worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
   - driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
   - executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
4. Restarted DSE cluster via OpsCenter

Answer (score 1):

By default, remote jmx monitoring is turned off in DSE 4.8.0 and up. Assuming that the ami is running a recent version of DSE. Then spark will be running on a DSE node. The docs are [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureJmxAuthentication.html) but here's a summary:

- edit cassandra-env.sh and set the following:

  ```
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
  LOCAL_JMX=no`
  ```
- copy jmxremote.password.template from your jre/jdk install location to /etc/cassandra and rename it to jmxremote.password

  ```
  chown cassandra:cassandra /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password
  chmod 400 /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password`
  ```
- Edit jmxremote.password and user and password.

  ```
  monitorRole QED
  controlRole R&D
  cassandra cass_password`
  ```
- Sorry about this one, but you have to add the user with r/w permissions to:

  ```
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
  ```

  I did this install on Ubuntu with Oracle Java 8 installed. Please change the path to match your java installation.

  ```
  monitorRole readonly
  cassandra readwrite
  controlRole readwrite \
  create javax.management.monitor.,javax.management.timer. \
  unregister
  ```

Restart cassandra and attach your jmx tools using the cassandra username and password.